# What causes remote desktop connection attempts to hang and then local Ctrl+Alt+Del to be ignored? Workaround without reboot?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, lock-screen, elevation, ctrl-alt-delete

I have a Windows 10 Pro machine running Terminal Server.  I always have a single logged in session and never logout (only disconnect).  Every so often it gets into a state where client RDP connections hang after successful (NLA) authentication and just show the "Please Wait" with the indefinite looping dots UI forever.  Once this happens, it will never resolve itself.  Restarting Terminal Services does not fix it.  It *may* be associated with a loss of network connection and a reconnection attempt by the RDP client.

In addition, after this occurs, unlocking the Windows session locally (using the physically attached keyboard/mouse/display) works fine, but then once unlocked, I cannot re-lock the session.  In other words, Ctrl+Alt+Del is ignored and does nothing, and any other method of locking the session also does nothing.  The only fix I have found is a reboot.

Edit: Also, the elevation prompt (consent.exe) will not appear on the local session when attempting to run something that needs elevation. So nothing can be elevated in this way.

I want to know:

1. What is causing this?
2. Is there a workaround that does not require a reboot or logout?  Is there a  process/service I can kill/restart while keeping the user logged in and all apps/windows running?

Edit: Note that I have the  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\IgnoreClientDesktopScaleFactor` registry key set to 1, and the Group policy for "`use wddm graphics display driver for remote desktop connections`" set to Disabled in an attempt to improve re-scaling performance and excessive window resizing/repainting at RDP connection time.

Comment: I've seen a similar issue impacting legacy 2008 R2 OS.  In that case, it was related to service controller contention.  Specifically, a background task auto-update program was trying to restart a service with failure restart options set.  Unfortunately, the service was crashing during restart, and the service controller was unable to fulfill the restart conditions due to files being locked by the update program.  My quick fix was to remove the failure restart options from services impacted by auto-updates. Once that was done, and the system rebooted, I no longer experiencing those RDP hangs.